# How to add trademark symbols

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to add a trademark symbol to all the instances of "Imagination Playground" in my HTML document. However I end up with something like this:

```
&lt;i class="fa fa-trademark"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;
```

It seems like the symbol I am using is converted to HTML characters. How can I escape that?

This is my original Ruby code:

```
body = "<p>Whether you want to build a playground, make play a priority in your community, or learn more about Imagination Playground , we've got webinars for you in March!</p>
  <p>As always, all our webinars are FREE. All you need to participate is a phone and a computer with an Internet connection.</p>"
new_body = Nokogiri::HTML(body)
new_body.encoding = 'UTF-8'
new_body.css('p','a').each{ |p|
p.content =  p.content.gsub(/Imagination Playground\s/,'Imagination Playground<i class="fa fa-trademark"></i>');
puts new_body
```

And this is what I get:

```
<p>Whether you want to build a playground, make play a priority in your community, or learn more about Imagination Playground&lt;i class="fa fa-trademark"&gt;&lt;/i&gt;, we've got webinars for you in March!</p>
<p>As always, all our webinars are FREE. All you need to participate is a phone and a computer with an Internet connection.</p>
```

How can I replace that HTML paragraph and escape ampersand and special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<p>Whether you want to build a playground, make play a priority in your community, or learn more about Imagination Playground , we've got webinars for you in March!</p>
<p>As always, all our webinars are FREE. All you need to participate is a phone and a computer with an Internet connection.</p>
EOT

doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'
doc.css('p').each do |p|
  p.children = p.content.gsub(/Imagination Playground\s/, 'Imagination Playground<i class="fa fa-trademark"></i>')
end
puts doc
```

Which results in:

```
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body>
# >> <p>Whether you want to build a playground, make play a priority in your community, or learn more about Imagination Playground<i class="fa fa-trademark"></i>, we've got webinars for you in March!</p>
# >> <p>As always, all our webinars are FREE. All you need to participate is a phone and a computer with an Internet connection.</p>
# >> </body></html>
```

Nokogiri is pretty smart. When it sees `children=`, it looks to see whether it's receiving a string. If so, it parses that string and converts it into a Node then replaces the existing children with the new node. This is a big difference from using `content=` which Nokogiri knows should be text, and then will encode the embedded tags into `&lt;`, etc. This is covered in the documentation.

For [`children=`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:children=):

> Set the inner html for this Node node_or_tags node_or_tags can be a Nokogiri::XML::Node, a Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment, or a string containing markup.

For [`content=`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:content=):

> Set the Node's content to a Text node containing string. The string gets XML escaped, not interpreted as markup.

---

> this would not work if i want to conserve the html tags that are inside the paragraph, try to do that for `<p>fsome test and then <b>bold</b></p>`

You are changing the requirements. Don't do that. Be specific about your needs so we can answer the real question once.

A small alteration is needed to take the contents of the desired tag. Use `children.to_html` to get the HTML string of the embedded nodes then `gsub` it and use its result:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>Imagination Playground<b>foo</b></p>')
puts doc.to_html
```

Which looks like this to start:

```
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><p>Imagination Playground<b>foo</b></p></body></html>
```

Modify the DOM:

```
doc.search('p').each do |p|
  p.children = p.children.to_html.gsub(/Imagination Playground\s?/, 'Imagination Playground<i class="fa fa-trademark"></i>')
end
puts doc
```

Which now looks like:

```
# >> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
# >> <html><body><p>Imagination Playground<i class="fa fa-trademark"></i><b>foo</b></p></body></html>
```

Notice I'm using `search` instead of `css`. Use the generic method instead of the more specific. It makes it easier to switch to XPaths if needed.

Also, I'm using a little more intelligent pattern in the `gsub` to conditionally grab a single trailing whitespace if it's available. It's not essential to do that with HTML because browsers gobble blanks, but it would be the right way to do it if you were dealing with regular text documents or preformatted text.

And, just for more detail about what Nokogiri is seeing:

```
doc.search('p').first 
# => #(Element:0x3fd222462204 {
#      name = "p",
#      children = [
#        #(Text "Imagination Playground"),
#        #(Element:0x3fd2224608f0 { name = "b", children = [ #(Text "foo")] })]
#      })
doc.search('p').first.children 
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd222461688 "Imagination Playground">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd2224608f0 name="b" children=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0x3fd22245fe64 "foo">]>]
```

Comment: Excellent explanation !!

Comment: this would not work if i want to conserve the html tags that are inside the paragraph, try to do that for `<p>fsome test and then <b>bold</b></p>`